# Scan PDF in Java

Tags: java, pdf

Whats the best way to scan a .PDF form using Java? Where the scanner object scans the .PDF form which has blank spaces for example; Name, Address, Phone Number etc. These spaces need to be filled in by an Interface then printed onto a new .PDF.

Comment: What does the IDE that you are using (Eclipse) has anything to do with your question?

Comment: perhaps s/he thought there may be a plugin available to assist with development...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse pdf files using Java you have plenty of options.

http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/

http://itextpdf.com/

http://www.jpedal.org/

http://pdfjet.com/os/edition.html

http://bfo.com/products/download.jsp

and many more

Comment: strangely you have not said about iText, which is probably the most used one, I think